# How to update JLabel text when varible from another class changes?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, timertask

I have `GUI class`, in which by clicking on `JButton pick_flower` instance of `Pick_Flowers class` is created and by clicking on `JButton make_fuel` instance of `Alchemy class` is created. I want to click on button once and then text will be changing depending on the value (sum of flowers or sum of fuel) now. For example, after 5 seconds sum of flowers will be 3 (so text of JLabel will be "3"), after 10 seconds sum will be 6 (so text of JLabel will be "6") etc. But in my GUI text of JLabel isn't changing (it's always "3" for flowers).

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    GUI g = new GUI();
}

public GUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Worker");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(panel);

    JLabel flower_count = new JLabel("0 flowers");
    panel.add(flower_count);
    Dimension flower_count_size = flower_count.getPreferredSize();
    flower_count.setBounds(800, 125, 200, flower_count_size.height);

    JLabel fuel_count = new JLabel("0 fuel");
    panel.add(fuel_count);
    Dimension fuel_count_size = fuel_count.getPreferredSize();
    fuel_count.setBounds(800, 275, 200, fuel_count_size.height);

    JButton pick_flower = new JButton("Pick flowers");
    panel.add(pick_flower);
    pick_flower.setBounds(600, 110, 130, 60);

    pick_flower.addActionListener(v -> {
        Pick_Flowers pick_flowers = new Pick_Flowers();
        flower_count.setText(android_helper.sum(pick_flowers.flowers)) + " flowers picked");

    });

    JButton make_fuel = new JButton("Extract fuel");
    panel.add(make_fuel);
    make_fuel.setBounds(600, 250, 160, 60);

    make_fuel.addActionListener(mi -> {
        Alchemy alchemy = new Alchemy();
        fuel_count.setText(android_helper.sum(alchemy.fuel_tanks) + " fuel extracted");
    });

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

     }
```

Here is `Pick_Flower class`:

```
     import java.util.*;

     public class Pick_Flowers {

GirlsList girlsList = new GirlsList();
List<Integer> flowers = new ArrayList<>();
Android_Helper android_helper = new Android_Helper();

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public Pick_Flowers(){
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override public void run() {
            flowerPicker();
        }
    }, 0, 5000);

}

public int flowerPicker() {
    int flower_picked = 1 * girlsList.flower_girls.size();
    flowers.add(flower_picked);
    System.out.println(android_helper.sum(flowers));
    return android_helper.sum(flowers);
}
      }
```

And `Alchemy class`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Alchemy{

GirlsList girlsList = new GirlsList();
List<Integer> fuel_tanks = new ArrayList<>();
Pick_Flowers w = new Pick_Flowers();
Android_Helper android_helper = new Android_Helper();

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

public Alchemy(){
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override public void run() {
           alchemyFuel();
        }
    }, 0, 15000);
}

public int alchemyFuel(){
    int flower_sum = android_helper.sum(w.flowers);
    System.out.println(flower_sum);
    int fuel = (flower_sum / girlsList.flower_girls.size()) * girlsList.alchemy_girls.size();
    fuel_tanks.add(fuel);
    int now_flowers = flower_sum - fuel;
    w.flowers = new ArrayList<>();
    w.flowers.add(now_flowers);
    return android_helper.sum(fuel_tanks);
} 
    }
```

Comment: Your GUI class has to define a method that sets the text of the JLabel.  This method is then called by the PickFlower or the Alchemy class timer method on the Event Dispatch Thread.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Answer (score 0):

You create new Pick_Flowers every time button is pressed, so flowers list is new every time too. Store Pick_Flowers in a variable outside of listener. Same thing for Alchemy.